# Glut Reshape Function Not Working

Tags: c, opengl, resize, glut, reshape

When I try to resize my glut window, the screen goes blank.

This is the code for the reshape callback funciton:

```
void Resize(int width, int height) 
{  
    CurrentWidth = width;
    CurrentHeight = height;


    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)CurrentWidth, (GLsizei)CurrentHeight); 

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity(); 
    glOrtho(0, CurrentWidth, CurrentHeight, 0, NearPlane, FarPlane);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

I am pretty new to the opengl world but from what I have learned this is supposed to work.

And this is all of the code put together:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>

#include "Utils.h"

int LEFT = 0;
int RIGHT = 0;
int UP = 0;
int DOWN = 0;

int CurrentWidth = 800,
    CurrentHeight = 800,
    WindowHandle = 0;

float NearPlane = 1.0f,
      FarPlane = 100.0f;

float lightX,
      lightY;

void Initialize(int, char*[]);
void InitWindow(int, char*[]);
void Idle(void);
void Resize(int, int);
void KeyPressed(unsigned char, int, int);
void SpecialPressed(int, int, int);
void SpecialReleased(int, int, int);
void Update(void);
void Render(void);
void FillZBuffer(void);
void ClearAlpha(void);
void RenderLightAlpha(float);
void GeometryPass(void);
void Draw(void);

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) 
{  
    Initialize(argc, argv);

    glutMainLoop(); 

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void Initialize(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    InitWindow(argc, argv);

    fprintf(
        stdout,
        "INFO: OpenGL Version: %s\n",
        glGetString(GL_VERSION)
    );

    lightX = 300.0f;
    lightY = 300.0f;
}

void InitWindow(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitContextVersion(3, 3);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE);

    glutSetOption(
        GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE,
        GLUT_ACTION_GLUTMAINLOOP_RETURNS
    );

    glutInitWindowSize (CurrentWidth, CurrentHeight); 
    glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);

    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_ALPHA);

    WindowHandle = glutCreateWindow ("Shadows");  

    if(WindowHandle < 1) {
        fprintf(
            stderr,
            "ERROR: Could not create a new rendering window.\n"
        );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glutDisplayFunc(Render); 
    glutReshapeFunc(Resize);
    glutIdleFunc(Idle);
    glutKeyboardFunc(KeyPressed);
    glutSpecialFunc(SpecialPressed);
    glutSpecialUpFunc(SpecialReleased);
} 

void Update()
{
    int speed = 10;
    if (LEFT)
    {
        lightX -= speed;
    }
    if (RIGHT)
    {
        lightX += speed;
    }
    if (UP)
    {
        lightY -= speed;
    }
    if (DOWN)
    {
        lightY += speed;
    }
}

void Draw()
{
    float x = 200;
    float y = 200;
    float w = 100;
    float h = 100;
    float depth = 0.0f;

    // floor
    glColor4f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    depth = -10.0f;
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    {
        glVertex3f(0, 0, depth);
        glVertex3f((float)CurrentWidth, 0, depth);
        glVertex3f((float)CurrentWidth, (float)CurrentHeight, depth);
        glVertex3f(0, (float)CurrentHeight, depth);
    }
    glEnd();

    // square
    glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    depth = -5.0;
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    {
        glVertex3f( x,  y, depth);
        glVertex3f( x + w, y, depth);
        glVertex3f(x + w, y + h, depth);
        glVertex3f(x,  y + h, depth);
    }
    glEnd();
}

void Render() 
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    Update();

    FillZBuffer();

    ClearAlpha();

    RenderLightAlpha(1.0f);

    GeometryPass();

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay(); 
}  

void FillZBuffer()
{
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);

    Draw();

    glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);
    glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
}

void ClearAlpha()
{
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_TRUE);
    glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glBegin (GL_QUADS);
    {
        glVertex2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2f((float)CurrentWidth, 0);
        glVertex2f((float)CurrentWidth, (float)CurrentHeight);
        glVertex2f(0, (float)CurrentHeight);
    }
    glEnd ();
}

void RenderLightAlpha(float intensity)
{
    float depth = -1.0f;  
    float radius = 300.0f;
    float angle;
    int numSubdivisions = 32;

    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    {
        glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  intensity);
        glVertex3f(lightX, lightY, depth);

        // Set edge colour for rest of shape
        glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        for (angle = 0; angle <= (float)PI * 2; angle += (((float)PI * 2) / numSubdivisions))
        {
            glVertex3f( radius*(float)cos(angle) + lightX, radius*(float)sin(angle) + lightY, depth);  
        }

        glVertex3f(lightX + radius, lightY, depth);
    }
    glEnd();
}

void GeometryPass()
{
    glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_DST_ALPHA, GL_ONE);

    Draw();
}

void Idle()
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void Resize(int width, int height) 
{  
    CurrentWidth = width;
    CurrentHeight = height;


    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)CurrentWidth, (GLsizei)CurrentHeight); 

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity(); 
    glOrtho(0, CurrentWidth, CurrentHeight, 0, NearPlane, FarPlane);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void KeyPressed(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(x);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(y);

    // escape key
    if (key == 27)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
}

void SpecialPressed(int keyCode, int x, int y)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(x);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(y);

    if (keyCode == GLUT_KEY_LEFT)
    {
        LEFT = 1;
    }
    else if (keyCode == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT)
    {
        RIGHT = 1;
    }
    else if (keyCode == GLUT_KEY_UP)
    {
        UP = 1;
    }
    else if (keyCode == GLUT_KEY_DOWN)
    {
        DOWN = 1;
    }
}

void SpecialReleased(int keyCode, int x, int y)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(x);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(y);
    if (keyCode == GLUT_KEY_LEFT)
    {
        LEFT = 0;
    }
    else if (keyCode == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT)
    {
        RIGHT = 0;
    }
    else if (keyCode == GLUT_KEY_UP)
    {
        UP = 0;
    }
    else if (keyCode == GLUT_KEY_DOWN)
    {
        DOWN = 0;
    }
}
```

Let me know if  you need anymore information.

Comment: Why do you believe that the "reshape" function has anything to do with your problem?

Comment: Why does your call to glOrtho only use the width?

Comment: @Bart Sorry it is supposed to be CurrentHeight, I changed it but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Nicol I didn't say that the reshape problem wasn't part of the problem, I just said that it should work but it doesn't.

Comment: Please don't add your solution to the question or add "Solved" to the title. Post your solution as an answer and then accept it.

Comment: @ChrisF I didn't and still don't see an option to answer my own question.

Comment: @ChrisF **Nevermind** I found it, I hadn't seen it earlier, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the FillZBuffer function the depth mask is disabled at the end and only re-enabled at the beginning of the same function. So when Render is called again, the call to clear the depth buffer bit does nothing because the depth mask is disabled.

To fix this the depth mask must be re-enabled before the call to clear the depth buffer bit.

So this is what Render should look like.

```
void Render() 
{
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE); // insert this line
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    Update();

    FillZBuffer();

    ClearAlpha();

    RenderLightAlpha(1.0f);

    GeometryPass();

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay(); 
}
```